# dict object has no attribute

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

In frontend I use vue js , using axios I sent data to backend.But after clicking submit button I got this error: dict object has no attribute 'invoice_products'.

From frontend using axios:

```
        this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/createTest', {
            invoice_products: this.invoice_products
        })
```

This is my json input data

```
{"invoice_products":[{"name":"fgf","price":"56"}]}
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createTest(request):
    serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data.invoice_products)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Error:
dict object has no attribute 'invoice_products'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.data` is a dict. So you access its info with `request.data[yourkey]` not `request.data.yourkey`

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def createTest(request):
    serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data['invoice_products'])
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Depending of what you serializer looks like, you may need to add `many=true` option to TestSerializer